# Header() is not executed (possible due to mail function)

Tags: php

On my [website](http://www.LolStreamGallery.net), I use a contact form, which causes me a lot of trouble. I already spent some time on actually getting the `mail()` PHP function working on 64bit Debian with exim4, but I finally did it, and mails are sent.

Now I am experiencing another problem, which I can't figure out how to solve. First of all the code.

```
<?php
$your_email = 'blahblah@gmail.com';
session_start();
$errors        = '';
$name          = '';
$visitor_email = '';
$user_message  = '';

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name          = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $user_message  = $_POST['message'];
    ///------------Do Validations-------------
    if (empty($name) || empty($visitor_email)) {
        $errors .= "\n Name and Email are required fields. ";
    }
    if (IsInjected($visitor_email)) {
        $errors .= "\n Bad email value!";
    }
    if (empty($_SESSION['6_letters_code']) || strcmp($_SESSION['6_letters_code'], $_POST['6_letters_code']) != 0) {
        //Note: the captcha code is compared case insensitively.
        //if you want case sensitive match, update the check above to
        // strcmp()
        $errors .= "\n The captcha code does not match!";
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        //send the email
        $to      = $your_email;
        $subject = "New form submission";
        $from    = $your_email;

        $body = "A user  $name submitted the contact form:\n" . "Name: $name\n" . "Email: $visitor_email \n" . "Message: \n " . "$user_message\n";

        $headers = "From: $from \r\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

        if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
            header('Location: http://www.lolstreamgallery.net/thank-you.html');
        } else {
            $errors .= "\n E-Mail coulnd be sent!";
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that that the header redirection is not working. The `mail()` does work, so the header should be executed. When I test the file locally, the redirection does occur.

If you wanna test the contact form, you can do it [here](http://lolstreamgallery.net/RequestStream.php).

[Here](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2ecd) is the whole file code:

EDIT2:

I'm now using the function of Ian Brindley which made the redirect work, but not the header function. It seems there is some output before the header.

Comment: Make sure that nothing on the page has been outputted before the `header` call. This includes any whitespace before the initial opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: Always use `exit` after `header`

Comment: what do you mean with whitespaces?? I only have some error output if an error appears. Aside from that i dont have any output I guess. I could show the whole code of the file if it is needed to. Thx for the advice of using exit, already did it know.

Comment: ok added the code of the whole file now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I cannot see any output before the header() call.

If there is no better alternative, here is a function I found a while ago which I now user for pretty much all of my redirects.

```
function redirect($url){
    if (!headers_sent()){    
        header('Location: '.$url);
        exit;
    }
    else {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'" />';
        echo '</noscript>'; exit;
    }
}
```

I know the non server side redirect is not ideal.

Comment: thx for the advice if I cannot get header working i will use this :)

Comment: Might be worth trying @mail()